# How to run database test in a Visual Studio Team Services build

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, localdb

I'm using Entity Framework Code First migrations (with Sql Server). For my tests, I create a test database for each execution (deleting it if exists):

```
// Is called once before any test is run.
[SetUpFixture]
public class Setup
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new TestDatabaseInitializer());
    }
    // ...
}

public class TestDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    MyDbContext _context;

    public override void InitializeDatabase(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
            // Remove database...
        }

        base.InitializeDatabase(context);
    }
    // ..
}
```

And the connection string for my test:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TaskRequirementsDb" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v12.0; Initial Catalog=db_test; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This works fine in my dev enviroment. So far no problem.

Now, I have a build in VSTS where **I want to run integrated tests with a database**. Is it possible? I read it is, because VSTS build servers come with MSSQL Server 2012 and MSSQL Server 2014 preinstalled (I'm using Hosted agent).
The problem is, **what connection string should I use?**

Note: I have already read this question:

[Database integration tests in Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602206/database-integration-tests-in-visual-studio-online)

But I don't know how apply this solution to my problem.

**Edit**

I've added a command line step (before running tests task) to create a localDb instance:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" create "v12.0" 12.0 -s
```

It is executed properly:

> [command]"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" create "v12.0" 12.0 -s
>
> LocalDB instance "v12.0" created with version 12.0.2000.8.
>
> LocalDB instance "v12.0" started.

But the result is the same. I'm getting the following error when tests are executed:

> [error]  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Comment: The other question says you have to have a step in the build to create a [LocalDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx), then in your tests you use the Local DB connection.

Comment: Yes, but my tests automatically create a database. I'm searching a solution in wich I don't have to change my tests implementation. I tried to change my connection string to LocalDb `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db_test.mdf;Initial Catalog=db_test; Integrated Security=True"`. But I get this error in build on passing my integration tests: "##[error]   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error ocurred..."

Comment: I created a simple a ClassLibrary project with EF code first and a UnitTest project to test database creating through EF, then queue build on hosted agent, it works fine. My build steps: Visual Studio Build, Command line (Tool: SqlLocalDB.exe, Arguments:create "v11.0" 12.0 -s, working folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn), Visual Studio Test. I shared my project on the OneDrive (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AresBGZVYryjhR6Z22WAZTP8CiCo) that you can make a test with it. On the other hand, you can share your project and build log on the OneDrive.

Comment: The command line step is the same I was using (except the instance name). Anyway if I follow your instructions I get this error: `Creation of LocalDB instance "v11.0" failed because of the following error: The parameter for the LocalDB Instance API method is incorrect. Consult the API documentation.` I've made some changes and I'm getting a different error. See my updates

Comment: Finally I solved my problem... My configuration and my build steps were OK. The problem was I had referenced one of my test projects (by mistake) in other test project and this project had not been configured properly yet. So my test were executed twice, once for each dll; the second time it crashed

Comment: @JoseAlonsoMonge Glad to hear that your issue has been solved, you can post an answer and mark it after 24 hours.